# How to keep the form of tensor wedge, instead of using tensor product?

Tags: tensors

[image]

Why is an expression with full form of

```
TensorProduct[TensorWedge[v1, v2], w1]
```

changed into

```
TensorProduct[
  Plus[
    TensorProduct[v1, v2], 
    Times[-1, TensorTranspose[TensorProduct[v1, v2], List[2, 1]]]], 
  w1]?
```

How could I keep the form unchanged?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with MMA v10, `FullForm[TensorProduct[TensorWedge[v1, v2], w1]]` prints `Out[]//FullForm=TensorProduct[TensorWedge[v1, v2], w1]`. What is your MMA version?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with MMA v12

Comment: I should try restarting Mathematica.  You may have accidently modified something.

Comment: I used MMA v11 student edition. I thought it may because I have defined (v1|v2) \\[Element] Vectors[d1]. I defined it this way because I want to use TensorReduce. But even under this definition, the FullForm[v1\\[TensorWedge] v2] is still TensorWedge[v1,v2]. I want to keep this form in the expression with TensorProduct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have done something like:

```
$Assumptions = (v1|v2) ∈ Vectors[d];
TensorProduct[TensorWedge[v1, v2], w1] //FullForm
```

> TensorProduct[Plus[TensorProduct[v1,v2],Times[-1,TensorTranspose[TensorProduct[v1,v2],List[2,1]]]],w1]

If you don't want the automatic simplification done by [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) to occur, just include the assumption using `Assumptions->assumptions` when you use [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) instead.